# Play Framework 2.x Can not output raw url in view

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to output the following raw url in the view.

https://loopme.me/api/vast/ads?appId=e18c19fa43&vast=2&uid=1234&ip=8.8.8.8&bundleid=com.loopme&appname=my_talking_pet&sdk=16.2&exchange=admarvel

however, even if I wrap the dynamic content with @Html method, the output is always 
https://loopme.me/api/vast/ads?appId=e18c19fa43&vast=2&uid=1234&ip=8.8.8.8&bundleid=com.loopme&appname=my_talking_pet&sdk=16.2&exchange=admarvel

that is to say, '&' is still escaped.

Can anyone help me to correctly output raw contents in the view? I'm using scala bases template engine.

code:

```
<vmap:VMAP xmlns:vmap="http://www.iab.net/videosuite/vmap" version="1.0">
    @for(offset <- timeOffsets){
    <vmap:AdBreak breakType="linear" breakId="@offset.id"
        timeOffset="@timeOffset(offset)">
        @for(campaign <- campaigns){
            <vmap:AdSource allowMultipleAds="allowMultipleAds"
                followRedirects="true" id="@campaign.id">
                <AdTagURI templateType="vast3">
                          <![CDATA[
                            @Html(campaign.extTag)
                          ]]>
                </AdTagURI>
            </vmap:AdSource>
        }
        <vmap:TrackingEvents>
            <vmap:Tracking event="breakStart">
                http://MyServer.com/breakstart.gif
            </vmap:Tracking>
        </vmap:TrackingEvents>
    </vmap:AdBreak>
    }
</vmap:VMAP>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a HTML template

```
import play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat
HtmlFormat.raw(yourURL)
```

In a XML template

```
import play.twirl.api.XmlFormat
XmlFormat.raw(yourURL)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it's still not working. '&' is still escaped.

Comment: Sure. @Html(campaign.extTag) still escape the tag url. And even if I use HtmlFormat.raw, the same result

Comment: In the view if you do `<code>@campaign.extTag</code>`. Do you get the same output? Doesn't `extTag` have the & already escaped?

Comment: Yes, the same output. I fetch the extTag from database, and in database, the & is still &, not escaped.

Comment: Are you generating a XML template? If so try instead `XmlFormat.raw(yourURL)`.